# Python split for desired results

Tags: python, split

```
a = "2121 the magic bus"
w, b = a.rstrip().split( ' ' )
```

Desired Results

```
w = 2121
b = the magic bus
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `maxsplit` argument of the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method. It specifies the maximum number of splits to do.

```
>>> a = "2121 the magic bus"
>>> w, b = a.split(maxsplit=1)
>>> w
'2121'
>>> b
'the magic bus'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way to do the job

```
a = "2121 the magic bus"

b = a.split() #split string a into elements (4 elements in this case) 

s = " " 

x = s.join(b[1:]) # join all elements starting from the second one ("the" in this case) 

c = eval(b[0]) # evaluate the first element of string a to integer

print("w = ", c)

print("b = ", x)
```

ouput

```
w =  2121
b =  the magic bus
```